# Enumerate all network interfaces with IPs on FreeBSD

Tags: network-programming, ipv6, freebsd, ioctl

My application needs to list all network interafaces on a machine and their IPs, IPv4 and IPv6.

I can get all interfaces with IPv4 IPs using ioctl(SIOCGIFCONF), but I need the IPv6 IPs, too.

On Linux, those can get gotten from /proc/net/if_inet6, but where would I get them on FreeBSD ?

Comment: The problem is that FreeBSD does not export `SIOCLGIFCONF` like Solaris and you cannot use `SIOCGIFCONF` on an IPv6 socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getifaddrs(3) provides portable way to get network addresses and interface names.